# Check whether the date time is in between two date time in database Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I'm newbie in php laravel. I'm currently working in my appointment system. I have two date, the start and end. I want to check if the date and time is in between of these two. Is there a Validation in between two date?

Answer (score 1):

Request Validation

```
$validation = $this->validate($request, [
    'date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|after_or_equal:startDateColumn|before_or_equal: endDateColumn',
    //...
]);
```

Elequent Query Check

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$count = Model::where('startDateColumn', '>=', $date)
              ->where('endDateColumn', '<=', $date)->count();
```

Then

```
if($count > 0) {
  // ...
} else {
 // ...
}
```